# In Racket, how do I create a syntax rule which can deal with multiple of one parameter?

Tags: racket

Kind of difficult to word the question in the title.

```
(define-syntax func
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((func a b c (d e) ...) (cond ((and (not (empty? d)) (not (empty? e))) (+ d e))
                                  )
                            )
    )
  )
```

If someone calls `(func a b c (1 1) (2 2))`, I would like it to add all `d`'s and `e`'s together. First, my code above produces an error

`syntax: missing ellipsis with pattern variable in template in: d`

and if it didn't even give me that error, I'm not even sure if it would add all of them together. I would also like it to do other things in case `d` and `e` were not provided, so I put it in a `cond`.

Thank you.

Edit:

```
(define-syntax func
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((func a b c (d e) ...)
     (cond
       ((and
         (not (empty? d))
         (not (empty? e)))
        (+ d e))))))
```

Comment: I have put better formatted version of your function at the end of your question. It makes it easier to understand the code.

Comment: `not` `empty?` as in `d` is a proper list with at least one element? Then how do you imagine `(+ '(... ) '(... ))` would work? Also know that `d` and `e` can be evaluated twice in this scenario.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes I know. It is not that great of a code. I am just trying to tackle the syntax. I just expect numbers to be entered.

Comment: If you do `(func 1 2 3 (4 5) (6 7))` what should it expand to? How it is now it ignores `a`, `b`, and `c` and it lacks the elipsis after the use of `d` and `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `something ...` will match zero or more elements. Thus in you pattern `(func a b c)` will match the rule.

If a pattern has elipses in the pattern it needs elipses in the expansion. Eg.

```
(define-syntax test
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a b ...)
     (if a (begin #t b ...) #f))))

(test 1)    ; ==> #t
(test 1 2)  ; ==> 2
(test #f 2) ; ==> #f
```

Comment: Which ellipses from the pattern match which ones from the expansion?

Comment: @ludluck In my example you see that `b` follows ellipses and thus the use of `b` in the result needs ellipsis too. I could have done `(list a b) ...` too an then it woudl expand to `a` and iterated over `b`s.